# plesk backup manager ftp setup but not taking backup to external FTP storage

Tags: plesk

In plesk control panel, the storage is full and no backup manager doesn't take any backup. So for that I have setup an external ftp storage.

As per docs, I have to enter FTP details in **Tools & Settings > Backup Manager > FTP Storage Settings **. Even though settings are correct no backup is being made. I have also tried enabling ftps and passive mode. Still the folder to which backups have to be made is empty! It's been some time and normal weekly backups don't end up in FTP storage. Did anyone else experience this issue? Any fixes for this?

[image]

Plesk version : Product: Plesk Onyx 17.8.11

Btw: ssh connection and filezilla connect flawlessly. So the username and password aren't the issue here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok found out why backups were not being taken!

There was one more option in `Tools > Backup Manager > Schedule`

Under `Store in` section `Ftp storage option` had to be checked.

In plesk docs it is not mentioned explicitly! https://www.plesk.com/kb/support/how-to-configure-ftp-backup-in-plesk/

Answer (score 1):

In Plesk, in order to transfer a backup to a remote storage by FTP, first a backup is provided on the server, then it is transferred to the remote server via the FTP. Even if you use the command line, there still needs to be enough free space to back up.

Comment: There is enough storage in server, but still backups are not being transferred to ftp